# Can I import a small laundry machine from Japan for resale in the U.S that is not UL certified?

Tags: ul

I am importing a small commercial laundry machine from Japan. It is currently not UL certified. Am I able to import this for resale in the U.S ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic for this stack

Comment: It's not illegal. By my reading there would likely be 1.4 to 3.5% tariff for such a machine if the *origin* is Japan (where it was manufactured, not where it was shipped from) depending on the exact HS code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is subject to specific export / import controls, bringing it to the US and selling it in of itself is not illegal. FCC compliance is more of a concern; if the device disrupts RF communications that would be illegal.

However you also expose yourself to significant liability. Much of the purpose of things like UL is so that vendors who wish to purchase product liability insurance can show to insurers that their product meets basic quality and safety stanards. Similarly things like ROHS show underwriters that your product won't make people sick.

I would consult a lawyer regarding what regulations are specific to your locality. California, for example, is more stringent than Texas.